# Setting font styles to OffscreenCanvas

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas

Is it possible to set `font-kerning` styles (or any other font style) to OffscreenCanvas?

In the example below I want to disable font kerning. Left: Canvas element, Right: OffscreenCanvas

[image: jsfiddle]

The example can be found here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darkowic/93uxkj1a).

Comment: if you change to `myOffscreenCanvas.style.backgroundColor = "red";` then it's become red, so some styles you can definately set. Also, the style property is undefined (after transforming), so to set styles, set first `obj.style = {}`, this will not cause an error, but will not have an effect, too

Comment: I've tried to set those styles directly to `offscreenCanvas` but it also has no effect. Looks like a chrome bug... Do you know where can I report it?

Comment: The bug is actually more that they do apply it for the "in-screen" canvas. Per specs, only the `direction` CSS rule should be inherited, if not set as a property, then from the source-element or the Document.